# Apply SCSS/CSS to :before where adjacent element class is X

Tags: html, css, sass

```
:before {
   margin: 10px
}
```

I would like to apply the above SASS/CSS to :before element in the following:

```
<div class="embed">
    :before
    <iframe class="my-iframe">
</div>
```

I do not want to apply the same css to the :before element in the following, the css should only apply when there is an adjacent iframe with class "my-iframe"

```
<div class="embed">
    :before
    <iframe class="some-other-iframe">
</div>
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize @at-root for this.

```
.my-iframe {
  color: blue;

  @at-root .embed:before #{&} {
    margin: 10px;
  }
}
```

Which compiles to

```
.my-iframe {
  color: blue;
}
.embed:before .my-iframe {
  margin: 10px;
}
```